# PHP CURL By Passing a Cookie Key/Value Pair

Tags: php, cookies, curl, key-value

I was wondering if someone knew the equivalent of doing (from terminal):

curl --cookie "session_id=12345" http://www.example.com

Using CURL in php.  I would prefer to do it without using a cookies.txt file by just doing the php curl calls by passing a cookie key/value pair. Please let me know if this makes sense, otherwise I can clarify further. I'm using this to connect to an API that requires sending a session variable via a cookie.

MORE CLARIFICATION:

The spec specifies this...

"The first thing that has to be done is to login. The response has a session id in it. This should be stored and used for subsequent calls. This should be added as a cookie, session_id, for further calls into the API."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `CURLOPT_COOKIE` as specified in the [`curl_setops`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) page.

```php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'session_id=12345');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For multiple cookies, separate with a semicolon and a space:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'session_id=12345; fruit=apple');
```

Comment: >> The contents of the "Cookie: " header to be used in the HTTP request. Note that multiple cookies are separated with a semicolon followed by a space (e.g., "fruit=apple; colour=red")

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the following flags:

- `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`

And:

- `CURLOPT_COOKIE`
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`
- `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`